# Windows7 says I have no Internet Connection through Wireless -- yet here I am!

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, troubleshooting

I just upgraded from Vista Home Premium x32 to Windows 7 Home Premium x32 and I noticed a very strange thing.  The Wireless bar graph on the bottom right of my toolbar shows a yellow exclamation point and if I dig deeper it says I have no Internet Connection (which is clearly false.)

I have two laptops with Windows7, the other one has Professional x64 and both are connected to the same WAP and both go through the same Linux Firewall/NAT Box.  The Win7 Professional does not show this behavior.  I've checked the firewall logs and nothing is being dropped.  I'm curious what Win7 is using to determine that my Internet is broken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I determined that the problem was that the Wireless network connection on this Laptop was set as 'Public' rather than 'Home'.  Win7 must have determined I have no Internet Connection when it saw a non-routable IP on a 'Public' network.

Comment: Then you might want to accept this answer or close the question so people know you're all set.